# How to download all documents from OWASP (github)?

Tags: security, github, owasp

I wanted to download all the documents from OWASP repository in github:

https://github.com/OWASP/DevGuide/find/dc5a2977a4797d9b98486417a5527b9f15d8a251

I haven't found an action button where I can download all documents in just one click (I need to enter each page to download).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the zip archive? https://github.com/OWASP/DevGuide/archive/2.0.1.zip .

By default, the page of a repository will give the link to download the zipped `master` branch, clicking on "Download ZIP" (on the right column). If you select the appropriate branch, in your case, the `2.0.1` branch, you can use the same "Download ZIP" which will targets the selected branch.

In a general way, in Github, you can download the content of a repository in the following way:

https://github.com/`user_or_organization`/`repository`/archive/`branch`.zip

Comment: Download the zip, and unzip it, you will get a local copy of all the content of the repository, there you will have all documents in .doc format.

Comment: But your zip contains only .md files, not .doc ones... What's the zip link for https://github.com/OWASP/DevGuide/find/dc5a2977a4797d9b98486417a5527b9f15d8a251 ?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/OWASP/DevGuide/archive/2.0.1.zip ``2.0.1`` is the github branch where the docs files are listed. Once you unzip the file, the docs files should be in the ``DevGuide2.0.1`` directory

Comment: But I didn't understand how do you know the links, because I don't see it on the page.

Comment: i've updated my answer above, i gave you some explanations where to download the zipped branch, and how the url is built.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the zip archive is probably best for your purposes (see @eblondel's answer) but if you have git on your system you could also just clone the archive:

```
> git clone https://github.com/OWASP/DevGuide.git
> git checkout 2.0.1
```

Then look in the 'DevGuide 2.0' directory of the resulting folder.